# How to define a piecewise function without "TypeError: cannot determine truth value"

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following code:

```
l = 2
h = 1
p = 2
q = -2
x = Symbol('x')
f = Piecewise ( (0, x < 0),
               (p, 0 <= x <= l/3),
               (h/l * x - h, l/3 < x  < 2*l/3),
               (q, 2*l/3 <= x  <= l),
               (0, x > l)
)
```

which results into a Error:

```
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

What is the proper way to define this function? I need sympy for this because I plan to integrate it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SymPy's Piecewise class [does not support chained inequalities](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8541) like `0 < x < 1`. It is possible to use `And(0 < x, x < 1)` instead, but in your example this is unnecessary. Recall that the conditions are evaluated from left to right; the first that evaluates to True wins. So you don't need `0 <= x` in the second condition, or `l/3 < x` in the third, etc. Your function should be defined by

```
f = Piecewise ( (0, x < 0),
                (p, x <= l/3),
                (h/l * x - h, x < 2*l/3),
                (q, x <= l),
                (0, True)
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This helped.

Comment: SymPy in general doesn't support chained inequalities, because they're [impossible to support](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#r72). You can use `And(0 < x, x < 1)`, or, as a shortcut, `Interval.open(0, 1).as_relational(x)`